# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ec2-user_din'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento-1.8, error, mysql

Hi I am trying to connect my MySQL database with my Magento site.

For further information I am using Magento 1.8.1, Apache 2.2.15, MySQL 5.5, PHP 5.3.28 & PhpMyAdmin and I am using Amazon Ec2 Linux instance and I run my store in localhost.

I transferred my Magento files in to var/www/html through filezilla ftp and imported the database through phpmyadmin.

When i tried to connect my site through my public ip i get the following error please help me to solve this issue..

```
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'ec2-user_din'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/trial/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/html/trial/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/html/trial/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/html/trial/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/trial/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /var/www/html/trial/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /var/www/html/trial/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/trial/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Comment: Please check ur local.xml file

Comment: It would probably help if you mentioned where the database came from (upgrade? migration?)

Comment: Hi psphan thanks for your quick reply initially i had my Magento site in my windows machine and then i exported the database from phpmyadmin and imported it to the amazon linux server.

Comment: i checked my local.xml file it is perfect.

Comment: Your local.xml file has incorrect credentials for MySQL. 100% guaranteed.   Either correct the local.xml file in app/etc or create / reset the credentials in MySQL.  If the user exists in MySQL and you reset the password, make sure you gave the user enough privileges.  Also after transferring a DB keep in mind depending on how you did it, MySQL user info doesn't come with it.   You may also need to flush privileges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Check the following:**

- Disable all 3rd party modules on the server you are copying from.
- Ensure that user ec2-user_din'@'localhost has been granted access to the database in question.
- Make sure you have reset the file permissions for your installation according to the [Magento Wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/resetting_file_permissions)
- On your MySQL server, create a username, password and database name that matches the one of your previous server.
- If you are still getting error messages, verify that the username, password and database name /app/etc/local.xml

If the above points do not work, follow this detailed [Magento Wiki to move your installation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/227/moving_magento_to_another_server) and see where you went wrong.

Comment: created a new user and assigned all privileges to him and entered the new values in local.xml and my problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

> Your `local.xml` file has incorrect credentials for MySQL. 100%
>   guaranteed. Either correct the `local.xml` file in app/etc or
>   create/reset the credentials in MySQL. If the user exists in MySQL and
>   you reset the password, make sure you gave the user enough privileges.

Taken from the comments. I can confirm that a password reset has worked for me.