# Site went down after last designer cleared cache

Tags: database, error, cache

Site went down after last designer cleared cache.

snappaneldisplays dot com

There has been an error processing your request

The user in the local.xml file is not the one listed there.

Anyone know of how to fix this? or what caused this?

### from the var/report

```
a:4:{i:0;s:98:"SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'snappae_snapn'@'localhost' (using password: YES)";i:1;s:2913:"#0 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(320): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/vegasdi1/public_html/snappaneldisplays.com/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Comment: Check your database connection in `app/etc/local.xml`.

Comment: did you checked db credentials?

Comment: changed the passwords of the main user and cleared cache folder neither worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your `local.xml` file has incorrect credentials for MySQL username, password, or the database. 100% guaranteed. Either correct the `local.xml` file in app/etc or create/reset the credentials in MySQL. If the user exists in MySQL and you reset the password, make sure you gave the user enough privileges.

Check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/25370/sqlstate28000-1045-access-denied-for-user-ec2-user-dinlocalhost-using/95888#95888).

Comment: unfortunately I tried that earlier, it didn't fix the issue. The designer said that he was editing it fine until he cleared the cache.

Comment: Try  to clear all the files out of `/path/to/magento/var/cache/*`, as Magento caches the contents of local.xml there. Also did you move the website from another server or any thing along with this?

Comment: No we didn't move it. it was working we are about to start making a few changes and cleared the cache and this happened. It was running fine previously.

Comment: the users in the cpanel have all privileges for that database.

Comment: Did it work or not? If not could you check the database server and the database it self. Also try to uncomment and comment these lines in the `index.php`  
                                                
>`#if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
>    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
>#}
>//Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
>ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: it did not work, I removed the cache folder earlier today, 

Fairly new to the magento world so bare with me.

the theme doesn't have a index file in it.

Comment: Could you check from the permissions on the `app/etc` folder cast seems to me Magento can't connect to the database and that caused by the locl.xml file so you should check that, if there is something wrong and the permissions is writable for the `app/etc` folder. Then could you do as I ask you in the previous comment and let me know what is the output in the homepage please :)

Comment: folder was 755 can't seem to find a theme folder in the skin folder to find the index.php, I'm thinking maybe the theme got erased. please hold. thanks

Comment: Hi, I hope you fix your problem, if you need anything, just ask  :)